# Can i specify the path of pdf transfer via itunes or other apps by info.plist or by code?

Tags: objective-c, file-transfer, info.plist

I am trying to do the pdf transfer via itunes or from other apps such as safari or gmail and i want to keep in consistent that pdf transferring via itunes or from other apps will be saved at the same file.

For itunes, i know that i can set the UIFileSharingEnabled property to YES to enable the file sharing, and then the document directory will be exposed to the users.

However, can i specify the path for explosure so that only specific sub-folder inside the document directory will be exposed instead of the whole document directory?

Secondly, I know that by setting certain property of the CFBundleDocumentTypes in the plist, other files in other apps such as safari or gmail can be chosen to open in my app. However, the path seems to be specified at Documents/inbox.

Therefore, i want to know that if there is a way to specify a custom path to save the pdf instead of saving at inbox?

Answer (score 0):

No, to both questions. If your app wants to use either of those file sharing APIs, and needs to store files that shouldn’t be user-visible, it should be storing the files somewhere other than the Documents folder.